# angularjs trustAsHtml detect click on image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to AngularJS, let' see if you can help me :)

I have a div containing the description of an activity.  This content it's in HTML so I'm using trustAsHTML:

```html
<div class="description-div">
  <div ng-bind-html="renderHtml(booking.description)">
  </div>
</div>
```

A $rootScope function:

```js
$rootScope.renderHtml = function (htmlCode) {
 return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
};
```

The description can contain images so I want to detect when there is a click on an image so I can open a popup with the image.

Can you help me?  I think I have to use a directive but I tried and it's not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to taint $rootScope with helper functions etc. it will grow into a hairy meatball.

One way to achieve what you want is with a directive:

```
app.directive("myBooking",["$sce", function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      booking: "="
    },
    template: "<div ng-click='click($event)' ng-bind-html='trustedHtml'></div>",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(scope.booking.description);
      scope.click = function($event) {
        if($event.srcElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
           // do something if this is the image of interest...
        }
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

Assuming the booking object is a property of a controller, within its scope use directive

```
<my-booking booking="booking"></my-booking>
```

The directive above assumes the img click event will bubble up, in other words the trusted HTML isn't consuming img click events.  Here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sP1HwS5Hhf5yftOcn42c?p=info) that demonstrates the directive.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm.